# Test library within the project

Tags: java, maven, testing, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I'm currently building a java utility library which can be use as maven dependency.

At the moment to simulate how the user use it, I need to create another project in intellij and put the dependency in the pom.xml

Does anyone know if there's any other way to test dependency without creating another project outside? I would like to keep all the tests in the same project.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly would you like to test? If a dependency in Maven works or your library? Do you have unit tests for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With maven and IntelliJ Idea you can create a project containing several modules. To achieve this, create a simple maven project and add following to its pom file:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Then right-click on the root of your project tree and select New > Module > Maven.
This will create a nested module. For your case you can create the main and the test modules and use them as dependencies for each other.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.I've tried this multiple modules, but I'm unable to create a clean jar only my module class. I've used maven-assembly-plugin with jar with dependencies, the jar included the child module dependencies in it.

Comment: You need to package all dependencies in your library jar?